# Monitoring a continuous Azure Web Job

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-application-insights

I have an Azure web app that runs a number of Web Jobs continuously.  The web app itself is empty.

I need to status information for these web jobs and I am planning to use Application Insights to achieve this.  Using custom events, I can provide the various pieces of information required.

However, I am not able to setup alerts on the custom events.  Is there a way to do so?  Are there any other azure tools that might be better suited to monitoring a continuously run web job?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create alerts for you AppInsights custom events as well.
On the azure portal click on the Custom Events tile and on top of that page, there is a Alert Rule menu:
[image]

take a look at this page for more details on custom events:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-insights-api-custom-events-metrics/